# How to find button by id from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an android app and I have a button that won't react when I press it. The button is supposed to bring up an alertdialog box. I'm very confused as I have an OnClickListener and the dialog box is instantiated.

Here is the code from the Java file:

```
public class tab1Expenses extends Fragment {

    Button btnEx;

    public class button extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tab1expense);
            btnEx = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEx);

            btnEx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(button.this).inflate(R.layout.add_ex, null);

                    AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(button.this);
                    add.setView(view);

                    add.setCancelable(true)
                        .setTitle("Enter Expense:")
                        .setMessage("Expense Name:")
                        .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });

                    Dialog dialog = add.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1expense, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

---

And here is my XML file that is related to the java file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ojemz.expensetracker.tab1Expenses$button"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<Button
    android:text="Add Expense"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnEx"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="800dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- TextView and other stuff -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why do you have an activity inside a fragment? that's just wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong!

The `button` class extending `Activity` has no reason to exist here.

If you simply want to get some `onClick` callbacks just do the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1expense, container, false);
    btnEx = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnEx);
    btnEx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(button.this).inflate(R.layout.add_ex, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(tab1Expenses.this.getActivity());
                add.setView(view);
                add.setCancelable(true)
                    .setTitle("Enter Expense:")
                    .setMessage("Expense Name:")
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                Dialog dialog = add.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    return rootView;
}
```

Don't forget to remove your "button" inner class.

**Side note**

You should rename your `tab1Expenses` `Fragment` class to `Tab1Expenses` in order to distinguish between instances and classes.

Please refer to [Java naming conversions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: that seems good except for in the LayoutInflater and Alerdialog declaration I put:
 ' View view = LayoutInflater.from(tab1Expenses.this).inflate(R.layout.add_ex, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(tab1Expenses.this); `

and it says it cant be applied

Comment: Builder
(android.content.Context)
in Builder cannot be applied
to
(com.example.ojemz.expensetracker.tab1Expenses)

Comment: I replaced tab1Expenses.this with rootview.getContext() and it worked! thank you so much

Comment: To get the context you can use this: tab1Expenses.this.getActivity()